# Como reverter tuplas apagadas por soft delete em Java (Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, delete

Java/Spring - Minha aplicação faz uso de Soft Delete para apagar os itens indesejados. Porém, em algumas situações, preciso reverter isso. Preciso reativar um item já apagado. Preciso listar todos os itens apagados por soft delete, ver qual deles preciso reviver e daí torná-lo ativo novamente. Como faço isso?

Answer (score -1):

Faça um delete lógico ao invés de um delete físico, só criar um campo active e quando for *apagar* bota como false. https://www.becomebetterprogrammer.com/soft-delete-vs-hard-delete/

Outra possibilidade é mover para uma outra tabela todos os items apagados, pode ser via trigger no banco ou dentro de transaction no seu código.

[trigger ao usar o delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10443862/10811254)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).